# C# Graphics object

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+

Question: How to check if `Graphics` object is usable.

My Problem: I create `Graphics` object from form and give it to "object X" for drawing, when form closes and "object X" tries to draw into `Graphics` object, GDI+ error occurs 0x80004005.

So i need to check if `Graphics` is drawable only having that `Graphics` object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your form is closed you should inform your "object X" of this fact...

Otherwise the only way to know if a Graphics object is accessible is to call a small method on it like [GetHdc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z5820hw.aspx) (with the correct [ReleaseHdc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.releasehdc.aspx) after if it succeed) and catch the error that may happens.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to draw objects is that handle the Paint event of the form. in the Paint() will you get access to Graphics which is drawable always. So you can use it without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Nice idea with GetHdc and ReleaseHdc, VirtualBlackFox, lucks like it worked.

Good job.